Disable gratuitous ARP messages
I'm working with LwIP on an STM32F746 on a specific embedded ethernet network. All nodes of this network are known (IP and MAC addresses).
I need my system to be able to answer to PING messages and ARP request, but never to send ARP requests itself or send gratuitous APR messages (announcement).
How do I disable the gratuitous ARP messages without disabling ARP?
